# Simulate/generate more data points off small dataset and constraints

Tags: r, data-transformation, dataset, data-preprocessing

I have a small data set only 18 data points, is there a way i could simulate or fabricate more data points but in the confides of those 18 data points.
Here is a screenshot of the data

I hope my q makes sense!
[image]

Comment: You will need to specify more than what you have to have a well-defined problem.

Comment: Yey, bootstrap!